# Winforms Notification Icon duplicates in the System Tray

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio

I am working on a WinForms application and have to show the Application Icon(Notification Icon) in the System tray. Things working fine. But when I go to a sub page from the main page and come back and check the system tray It has 2 notification Items in the system tray. Again When I go to another page and see, another duplicate  Icon appears in the system tray. Like that the number of notification icons gets increase when i go to another page and come back.

If someone can Guide me where I have gone wrong, really appreciate. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're not giving any code, I'm gonna go on hunches and lucky guesses:

- The logic you implemented to generate a notification icon gets executed on an event that occurs when you change page in your app. (Likely)
- There is a chipmunk that lives inside your computer, and he felt like monday is messing-with-da-master day. (Not so likely)

Comment: Everybody knows that for monsters, monday is lazy day. Definitely no energy to mess around with any master whatsoever. I'd definitely focus on the first point.

Comment: Yes thats right. I normally passes the current instance of the main page for next page. The mistake I did was in the second page I Globally creted a new instance of the main page and in the constructor I initialize it to the object pass by the constructor.. Thanks for the clue... As U guess its not a work done by the Chipmunk who exists inside my computer. Thanks..